# How to get all IDs from Mongo with no record in the past hour

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Considering the following documents:

```
[{
    "imei": "352413080100000",
    "datestamp": "2019-03-25T19:17:11.471Z"
}]
```

How can I get a unique list of all imei where there is no record for the past hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation to find the unique record for the `imei` field and use `moment` library to cut of the last hour from the current time.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "datestamp": {
      "$lte": moment().subtract(1, 'hours').toDate()
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": '$imei'
  }}
])
```

Or even you can use distinct query as well

```
const imeis = await db.collection.distinct('imei', { "datestamp": { "$lte": moment().subtract(1, 'hours').toDate() } })
console.log(imeis)
```